# Laravel wherenotin wrong results

Tags: php, laravel

My php Code

```
$AllAdTypes = UserAdTypes::where('ad_id', $value)
        ->whereNotIn('ad_typeprice_id', array($ArrString[$i - 1]))
        ->orderby('created_at', 'ASC')->orderby('ad_id', 'ASC')
        ->select('ad_typeprice_id')->lists('ad_typeprice_id');

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
return $last_query = end($queries);
```

Last Query:

```
Array ( [query] => select `ad_typeprice_id` from `UserAdTypes` where `ad_id` = ? 
and `ad_typeprice_id` not in (?) order by `created_at` asc, `ad_id` asc 
[bindings] => Array ( [0] => 82 [1] => 4, 10, 18, 27, 36, 7, 16, 11, 21, 19, 12 ) 
[time] => 0.44 )
```

when i tried in sql, it is ok.

```
SELECT  `ad_typeprice_id` 
FROM  `UserAdTypes` 
WHERE  `ad_id` =82
AND  `ad_typeprice_id` NOT 
IN ( 4, 10, 18, 27, 36, 7, 16, 11, 21, 19, 12 ) 
ORDER BY  `created_at` ASC ,  `ad_id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

SQL Result: "13"

But i dont know, query is right. And i tested on sql. And result is wrong.

Laravel Query Result

```
Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 18 [2] => 12 [3] => 19 )
```

if you check "$last_query" result, i need only show ([0] => 13).

Comment: Is `$ArrString[$i - 1]` a string? If so, can you make it an _array_ of those values? Right now, it probably does a `NOT IN('4, 10, 18, 27, 36, 7, 16, 11, 21, 19, 12')` (note the quotes).

Comment: Yes return string. "4, 10, 18, 27, 36, 7, 16, 11, 21, 19, 12"